# Running Oozie SSH + Java Action

Tags: hadoop, oozie

How to run a **SSH+JAVA Action** ? .

I need to run SSH action to my remote machine. In which in my remote machine i had a jar file + properties file  has to get executed. 
How to write a workflow for this ?

In that case whether jar file will be copied from oozie lib folder to the remote machine . If so in which place it will be copied **/home/user/oozie-oozi/**

I had wrote a workflow like below

```
   <action name="ssh-FileValidation">
    <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
         <host>user@myremotenode-ip</host>
            <command>/home/user/testscript.sh</command>
    </ssh>
    <ok to="mr-job"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

For the Above solution i need to copy the jar file and Properties file to my remote machine.

Is there any other way in that i need not required to copy jar file to each machine . As while running oozie ,oozie itself will copy required jar file to the location in which jar will be getting executed

FYI, But remote machine mounted in hadoop installed cluster only .

Answer (score 0):

Put your jar into `lib` directory near your `workflow.xml` in HDFS, and properties file near `workflow.xml`:

```
/user/syed/super-oozie-app/
  workflow.xml
  super-oozie-app.properties
  lib/
    super-oozie-app.jar
```

Then you can define Java action as follows (supposing com.example.SuperOozieAppAction class is located in `super-oozie-app.jar` and it has `main` method that you want to run):

```
<action name="super-oozie-app-action">
    <java>
        ...
        <main-class>com.example.SuperOozieAppAction</main-class>
        <file>super-oozie-app.properties#super-oozie-app.properties</file>
    </java>
    ...
</action>
```

This way Oozie solves the problem of files distribution for you. `SuperOozieAppAction` will be started and `super-oozie-app.properties` will be located in its current directory.

Read more about java actions [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action) and about files distribution [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.2.1_Adding_Files_and_Archives_for_the_Job).

Comment: How is it possible with SSH + Java ?

Comment: You don't need to use SSH in this case. Oozie and HDFS handle files distribution for you.

Comment: I need to run the Java action in specific machine So how can you define that ?

Comment: Actually Oozie runs Java action as single-mapper MR job, so it cannot guarantee that mapper will start on specific machine. Why do you need that?

Comment: I am trying to copy some files from the specified machine to hadoop cluster ?

Comment: In this case I would implement this as simple Cron (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job that executes bash script with `hadoop fs -put ...` commands. Oozie + Java is overkill for such task.

Comment: Also in our infrastructure we have a couple of SFTP servers from which we copy files into HDFS using Oozie + Java action. This way we pass SFTP credentials to Java action and retrieve files using JSch library (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), then write into HDFS with standard HDFS Java API.

Comment: No i am getting delta data to that location and i am also doing the business implementation. So i need to run java program from that location .

Comment: You can copy delta data into HDFS and then do business implementation in separate MR which will read from HDFS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57382/discussion-between-syed-abdul-and-dmitry).